# Set nth property from object

Tags: javascript

How can I use JavaScript to set for example the third property from an object. For example I have the following JSONP in the head of the HTML:

```
var translations = {
    "domain" : null,
    "plural-forms" : "nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);",
    "messages" : {
        "Home" : ["Strona G\u0142\u00f3wna"],
        "Go to our YoYo Games Archive" : ["Przejd\u017a do Archiwum Gier YoYo"],
        "Welcome" : ["Witamy"]
    }
};
```

To access the translation of the third message I do this: `Object.values(translations.messages)[2]`, but now I want to *set* it.

Thanks for any help in advance. :)

Comment: The so called third key is an array, do you want to push element to this array?

Comment: Object properties are _unsorted_, so _third property_ of object is nonsense.

Comment: Just access it like that : translations.messages.Welcome... It makes no sense trying to access the nth property of an object because the numbering can change...

Comment: What JS engine are you using?  Object.values() is not a function in Chrome, at least.

Comment: @Paul I'm using Firefox... I guess I can use one of the polyfills on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) for Chrome and Safari. Can I just include polyfill.js in the head or do I need any of the other files?

Comment: The answer I gave doesn't rely on a non-standard function, so you should be able to use it without polyfills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first off that's not JSONP, it's just a JS object.

`translations.messages["Go to our YoYo Games Archive"] = "new value"` will work, not sure why you want to do it via the nth item.

If you really need to do it based on position instead, you can always do:

```
var key = Object.keys(translations.messages)[2];
translations.messages[key] = "new message";
```

Comment: This is perfect! I wanted to set the messages based on position, because I'm using a grid POST form for a language file updater and the form text areas are given an identifier based on their position. :) Yeah I think I misunderstood the concept of JSONP, I think I understand now (JSON with a callback function).

Comment: I would (as others have said) still not rely on the position.  The position of keys in a JS object are not guaranteed, especially across encoding/decoding (e.g. parsing a form body).  Most well built form libraries use form element names that can be parsed into the structure you want, e.g. `<input name="translations.messages['whatever']" value='some message'`>

Comment: Thanks, I went with giving the text areas a name. Strange that I hadn't thought of this before. xD http://gamemaker.mooo.com/ar/language-updater